# PhpStorm | PHPUnit | Feature test | Xdebug | Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, xdebug

I have used a feature test of PHPUnit. When my herd (I use `Herd` for local development) updated PHP - I received that strange exception when I launched the feature test:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

[image]

I expected that the feature unit test will works.

Stack with issue:

- php8.1 (Xdebug - 3.3.1)

Comment: Did you fixed it or not? I am confused. If you did fix it and want to share it (as I see no edit and you directly posted everything together), just post an answer and mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

After some searching - I have found that it looks like some issue with xdebug of the 3.3.1 version (I also had this version Xdebug after update PHP).

As I use herd, I have found a possibility to change the current version of my Xdebug to 3.2.2.

## **My solution:**

**Downgrade Xdebug version from 3.3.1 -> 3.2.2**

Change xdebug version for herd:
Here you can found how add the additional extension for herd:
https://herd.laravel.com/docs/1/advanced-usage/additional-extensions#adding-extensions

In my case, I simply installed a new version
pecl install xdebug-3.2.2

**Extension location:**
On an M1/M2 Mac, the extension can be fount at /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl. On an Intel Mac, it will be at /usr/local/lib/php/pecl.

The whole path in my case:
/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so

In the phpstorm I have changed the debugger extension path to a new one and it started works

Source where I have found information about issue with xdebug version:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-68171/Process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-SIGSEGV#focus=Comments-27-8664531.0-0

[image]